# To access table of another schema using Dynamic SQL statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYN_TAB(TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI' || TABLE_NAME ||
                                                            '_TOCINSTANCE';
END DYN_TAB;
```

It shows the below error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

How to access the oracle table from one instance from another instance without using data link.

Sorry for the confusion

Below is the static sql query and it works perfectly, I am running the below query in
KMDPO which is a schema and ILX2012_KMDEPOT is another schema and both are in the same database.

```
SELECT * FROM ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE;
```

Comment: If the table is really in a different database (using the Oracle definition of "database"), you'd need to use a database link.  If the table is really in a different schema in the same database (what other RDBMS products refer to as a "database" is most similar to what Oracle calls a "schema") then you need to prefix the object name with the schema name (which you appear to be doing here) and you need to have privileges on the object in question.

Comment: Both table are in the different schema on the same database, by the way if i use like static sql then it is working, only dynamic queries are not working...

Comment: Now I'm confused.  Your subject and your question talks about accessing tables from "another database" and "another instance".  Now, it sounds like you're saying that you want to access a table in the current schema of the current database.  Is your `dyn_tab` procedure created in the `ILX2012_KMDEPOT` schema?  Or is that procedure created in some other schema of the same database?

Comment: What does the successful static query look like? I'm wondering if you're just mangling the table name, maybe missing an underscore after the AOI part?

Comment: As @AlexPoole has requested, please edit your question and add the static SQL which works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this a few different ways and see where things go wrong. First, try the following:

```
DECLARE
  csrStatic  CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE;
  aRow       ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE%ROWTYPE;
  nRowcount  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  OPEN csrStatic;

  LOOP
    FETCH csrStaticINTO aRow;
    EXIT WHEN csrStatic%NOTFOUND;

    nRowcount := nRowcount + 1;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csrStatic;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nRowcount || ' rows fetched');
END;
```

If that worked, run the following:

```
DECLARE
  csrDynamic SYS_REFCURSOR;
  aRow       ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE%ROWTYPE;
  nRowcount  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  OPEN csrDynamic for 'SELECT * FROM ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE';

  LOOP
    FETCH csrDynamic INTO aRow;
    EXIT WHEN csrDynamic%NOTFOUND;

    nRowcount := nRowcount + 1;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csrDynamic;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nRowcount || ' rows fetched');
END;
```

If the above worked, try the following:

```
DECLARE
  csrDynamic    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  strTablename  VARCHAR2(100) := '659';
  aRow          ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI659_TOCINSTANCE%ROWTYPE;
  nRowcount     NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  OPEN csrDynamic for 'SELECT * FROM ILX2012_KMDEPOT.AOI' ||
                      strTablename || '_TOCINSTANCE';

  LOOP
    FETCH csrDynamic INTO aRow;
    EXIT WHEN csrDynamic%NOTFOUND;

    nRowcount := nRowcount + 1;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csrDynamic;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nRowcount || ' rows fetched');
END;
```

Try all three and see what errors (if any) are produced.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I will try, Is using the Cursor the only solution?.

Comment: If you want to you could use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...INTO...` if you know that the SELECT statement will only find a single row, or use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...BULK COLLECT INTO...` to gather all the (multiple) rows into a collection. [Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#CJACGJJG). Best of luck.